# Implementing SSO in Salesforce - NetSuite

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, netsuite

My use case is, i need to open NetSuite within Salesforce using SSO. Both the platform supports SAML 2.0.
As a first step mentioned in [SSO implementation guide in Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/), I am trying to create new Single Sign On Setting from  'New From Metadata Url' button. And here is NetSuite Service Provider metadata url:
https://system.na1.netsuite.com/saml2/sp.xml

However, Salesforce is throwing an error-
The XML file doesn't include your SAML 2.0 settings. Verify that the URL links to the SAML 2.0 settings you want.

I checked the NetSuite SSO metadata xml (provided in the url path) and that contains definition for SAML2.0. So not sure why this error is coming up. Can anyone suggest here what might be wrong? Or if I am missing something here.

thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your use case?  Are you trying to sync data across systems?  Or, are you trying to actually log into NetSuite from Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that both Salesforce and Netsuite are Service Provider implementations. Neither is an Identity Provider so if you are importing Netsuite's metadata to Salesforce you'd get an error because you are importing the wrong sort of file.